# Allow date only 18+ years in input field type="date"

Tags: javascript, html, validation, view, user-input

I want an input field that only allows dates for people older than 18:

```
<input id="txtDOB" type="text" name="txtDOB">
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The title says `type="date"` the example `type="text"`.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: And read this too https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You going to have to write some JS

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear()+18;
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("txtDOB").setAttribute("max", today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wimanicesir's answer was good but I'd make one change, instead of adding 18 we would need to subtract 18 to get a max of 18+ years old.

```
const today = new Date()
let dd = today.getDate()
let mm = today.getMonth()+1 // January starts at 0, so we add 1 to get  the correct number for the month.
let yyyy = today.getFullYear() - 18; 
 
if(dd<10)dd = "0"+dd
if(mm<10) mm = "0"+mm

today = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`

document.getElementById("txtDOB").setAttribute("max", today);
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment on @Wimanicesir post

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's answer has a syntax error. `today` variable can't be reassigned since it's a const.

Here's a shorter and correct answer based on Patrick's solution.

```
const eighteenYearsAgo = () => {
    const today = new Date()
    let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, 0)
    let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, 0)
    let yyyy = today.getFullYear() - 18;

    return `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`
})
```